# BIND give DNS record only from alive web server

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, failover

I want to configure failover dns records for my web service.
I want configure something like geo dns, I want check alive web server and BIND must give only alive DNS record
For example if host A with ip 1.1.1.1 down, BIND must give DNS record for secondary host B with ip 2.2.2.2
I cant find this feature in BIND. 
How to realise this scheme? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Go pro and use something like keepalived or pacemaker/corosync.

I only know of Route53 on AWS which does support health checks on DNS records.